# How to split field value based on percentage of total

Tags: python, pandas

I have sum of transactions grouped by `date_month`, `device` and `channel` like so

```
date_month   device            channel  transactions
2017-01-01  desktop         AFFILIATES           413
2017-01-01   mobile         AFFILIATES           501
2017-01-01    other         AFFILIATES            22
2017-01-01   tablet         AFFILIATES           250
2017-01-01  desktop             DIRECT         13979
etc...       etc...             etc...        etc...
```

date_month range is from `2017-01-01` to current date

What I'm trying to do is split the `device`'s `other` field into either `mobile`, `desktop` or `tablet`

Example process:

- Pivot device `'other'` with its value `transactions` as an extra column (`other_transactions`)
- Take a total sum of `transactions` partitioned/grouped by `date_month` and `channel` (`total_transactions`)
- Then divide `transactions` by `total_transactions` to get percent total (`percent_total`)
- Multiply `other_transactions` and `percent_total` to get `other_split`
- Add `other_split` to `transactions` to get an updated transactions field

Getting the totals and applying simple math operations shouldn't be a problem. I would do something along the lines of `df['total_transactions']=df.groupby(['date_month', 'channel'])['transactions'].transform('sum')` to get `total_transactions` but the issue I'm having is getting the `other` transactions into a separate column like so

```
date_month   device            channel  transactions  other_trans
2017-01-01  desktop         AFFILIATES           413           22
2017-01-01   mobile         AFFILIATES           501           22
2017-01-01   tablet         AFFILIATES           250           22
2017-01-01  desktop             DIRECT         13979          etc
etc...       etc...             etc...        etc...
```

In the end, I would like to have a data frame that removes `other` devices from the `device` column and uses its transactions to increase the remaining device transactions based on their share of transactions for that `date_month` and `channel`

Comment: In your expected output, where does `234` in `other_trans` comes from?

Comment: It would've been the next partition/group's other transaction. I'll remove it to avoid confusion as it's just an example

Comment: I think you should include it rather than remove it. Right now it is hard to judge what your expected output is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can first create another dataframe using `groupby`, drop the rows with `others`, and then perform a `merge`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'date_month': {0: '2017-01-01', 1: '2017-01-01', 2: '2017-01-01', 3: '2017-01-01', 4: '2017-01-01', 5:"2017-01-01"},
                   'device': {0: 'desktop', 1: 'mobile', 2: 'other', 3: 'tablet', 4: 'desktop', 5:"other"},
                   'channel': {0: 'AFFILIATES', 1: 'AFFILIATES', 2: 'AFFILIATES', 3: 'AFFILIATES', 4: 'DIRECT', 5: 'DIRECT'},
                   'transactions': {0: 413, 1: 501, 2: 22, 3: 250, 4: 13979, 5: 234}})

other = df.groupby("device").get_group("other")[["date_month","channel","transactions"]]

df = df.drop(df[df["device"].str.contains("other")].index)

df = df.merge(other, on=["date_month","channel"], how="left", suffixes=("","_other"))

print (df)
```

Result:

```
   date_month   device     channel  transactions  transactions_other
0  2017-01-01  desktop  AFFILIATES           413                  22
1  2017-01-01   mobile  AFFILIATES           501                  22
2  2017-01-01   tablet  AFFILIATES           250                  22
3  2017-01-01  desktop      DIRECT         13979                 234
```

Comment: Of course...why did I not think of that! You are a legend sir